# A function is continuous if and only if its composition with the inclusion map is continuous.

Tags: general-topology

I want to show that if I have space $X, Y$ and a subspace $A \subset X$ with subspace topology then $f: Y \to A$ is continuous if and only if $\iota \circ f: Y \to X$ is continuous, where $\iota: A \hookrightarrow X$ is the inclusion map.

I have shown that $\iota$ is continuous from basic definitions. I have also shown the forward implication: the continuity of $f$ means that $f^{-1} \circ \iota^{-1}$ will always pull out neighborhoods. I'm having trouble showing the converse where the continuity of $f$ comes from the continuity of $\iota \circ f$. I've tried working with the open set definition of topologies, but the key problem is that open sets in $A$ may not be open in $X$, so I'm having trouble relating $\iota^{-1} \circ f^{-1}: X \to Y$'s behavior on open sets to $f^{-1}: A \to Y$'s behavior.

In general, we know that if $f, g$ are continuous then $f \circ g$ is continuous. Under what conditions can we say the converse is true?

Comment: I guess $f(x)=g(x) =1/x$ is an example of "not always".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose $\iota\circ f$ is continuous, that is, for every open set $U$ in $X$, $f^{-1}(\iota^{-1}(U))$ is open in $Y$. But $\iota^{-1}(U)=U\cap A$, which is an open set in $A$. And every open set in $A$ can be written as $U\cap A$ for some open set $U$ in $X$. It's now easy to show $f$ is continuous by definition.

In general, we can not say anything about the continuity of $f$ and $g$, when $f\circ g$ is known to be continuous. However, in this case things are different. The fact is sometimes called the characteristic property of subspace topology.

Comment: The key observation I was missing was: $\iota^{-1}(U) = U \cap A$. Thank you! Future readers should see gary's answer for a slick approach.

Answer (score 1):

I think if you restrict your domain, you can define $ \mathbb i^{-1} $ so that it is continuous. Then EDIT , As Shuckles pointed out  $f=i^{-1}\circ (i \circ f)=f $ is a composition of continuous functions.

Comment: $\iota \circ \iota^{-1} \in X$, but the domain of $f$ is $Y$ so I'm not sure how you can compose $f \circ \iota \circ \iota^{-1}$.

Comment: Let me see if I can make it work..

Comment: I think $f = \iota^{-1} \circ (\iota \circ f)$ is exactly what you want. This is a really neat approach.

Comment: I was about to say just that. Thanks.

Comment: But why is $i^{-1}$ continuous?